# How to use IdlingResource for Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, testing, synchronization, android-jetpack-compose

I understand how to use the EspressoIdle resource for my purposes. But what about Compose? It is said that it could be done the same as with the espresso idling resource (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing#idling-resources). Unfortunately, I can't find any example of that.
I want to skip any Loading state before making an assertion, but I can't figure out how it could be done. For exclusive tests, I can easily pass a certain state, but for end-to-end testing with the mock server, I need to use something like an idling resource.
Does anyone have any ideas on how it could be implemented?

Comment: So far I've decided to use `composeTestRule.waitUntil(DELAY_MS)`. In the body of the function, I could check my viewState: when one is in one's appropriate state I'm making an assertion.